# Is int type in Dart a value type or reference type?

Tags: flutter, dart

The int type in Dart has default value of null. null is an object of type Null class. (as per Dart documentation). Also, in Dart, int derives from class Object.
Hence,

```
int i = 10;
print(i.runtimeType is Object);   // returns true
```

This makes me believe that int is not a value type like in other languages (such as C#) but a reference type.

If I am correct, then-
`int i = 10;`
means i is a reference variable holding the reference to an int object 10.

Is this correct? If not, I would appreciate if a link to the description in the documentation is shared.
Till now, I've been unable to find any proper explanation and hence have come to this conclusion myself.
Thanks.

Comment: Since `int`s are immutable, I don't think that there is any observable distinction.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, Dart's `int` type is a "reference type".
Dart does not have value types at all, all values are instances of a class, including integers. (At least technically, function values makes their classes very hard to see.)
EDIT: With records, it's ... complicated. They're technically reference values, but ones that don't have a fixed identity. Or rather, any attempt to compare record references for being references to the same object, is always free to say `false`.

Integers are *immutable* and pretends to be *canonicalized*.
If `a` and `b` are `int` values and `a == b`, then `identical(a, b)` is guaranteed to be true, so `a` and `b` looks like they are the same object, but it's unspecified whether that's because they really are the same object, or because `identical` just cheats and does `==` for integers.

That means that you can largely treat `int` as a "value type". Whether it is copied on assignment or parameter passing, or you are passing a reference to the same object, is impossible to tell apart. The language ensures that, because it allows the implementations to do whatever is more efficient.
In practice, some integers are unboxed inside functions, some integers are stored as a value in the reference itself, and some are real objects.
(That's also one of the reasons you can't use an `Expando` with an `int`).

(In the current Dart language, all types annotations are nullable, meaning that you can assign `null` to `int x;`. With the upcoming Null Safety feature, that changes. Types will only be nullable if you write them as such, so `int x = 1;` would not accept a `null` value, but `int? x;` would. And `null` is an object too, the only instance of the class `Null`.)

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a value type in the sense that if you pass `int` value into a function and change the value of a parameter inside function, it won't affect outer scope.

```dart
void add(int inner) {
  inner += 1;
}

int outer = 0;
add(outer);
print(outer); // 0, unchanged
```

But `int` is still a class even though its name starts from lowercase letter. There was a [huge discussion](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1410) about its naming and lots of people consider it an inconsistency.

Comment: if I change int to String in your given example and do inner += "1" inside add, even then the value of outer is not changed. Hence by your logic even String acts as a value type, even though it isn't... hence this example isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Dart is an object, int, double or num may look like keywords but they are built-in abstract classes. Since they are abstract classes which means they can not be instantiated, they do not start with an uppercase letter.

try this line,
 `print('2  is instance of "int" class :\t${ 2 is int}');`

this will result in true.

And regarding your concern about 'null' :
In Dart, like JavaScript and Python, everything that a variable can hold is an object including null. Every object including null is an instance of some class and all these classes inherit from Object class.

your can refer [this link](https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-variables-and-data-types-d269ea7d1f8f) for more info.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `int` is a class (it even extends `num`) and therefor has common methods to use on. But one the other side it is different than "normal" classes since you don't have to use a constructor like

```dart
int i = int(3);
```

See int's class documenation https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/int-class.html