# What is "reference type","value type","canonicalized" in Dart? (concrete definition)

Tags: flutter, dart

https://dart.dev/guides/language/coming-from/js-to-dart#built-in-types

> In Dart, all types are reference types, meaning that all variables
> refer to an object (an instance of a class). However, the types int,
> double, String, and bool are implemented to be immutable (unchanging)
> and are canonicalized, which means they behave as if they are value
> types.

I often see this kind of explanation in many places, but

"value type",

"reference type",

"canonicalized",

I have never seen a ***concrete*** definition of the above terms. I think it is necessary to define these terms in the Dart language because it is an explanation of the Dart language, but does it exist in the official documentation or anywhere else?

If you have a document with ***specific*** definitions of these terms in Dart,(or in other language), I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

If not, in what language are these terms used?
Since the above page is an article about comparing JavaScript and Dart, is it a definition of JavaScript?

Or is it a definition of the Swift language or something?

After all, if these terms are explained as terms in other languages, I think that it is necessary to experience these languages as prerequisite knowledge in order to learn Dart. What is this?

---

Does the term "canonicalized" in Dart mean "constant value" after all?

```
void main() {

  int outer = 0;

  int other = outer;

  other = 1;
  print(outer); // 0 (not changed)

}
```

The implication of this behavior(result) is that, after all, int-type literals are const constants, aren't they?

Or it means that it behaves the same as the const constant.

Is that the definition of "canonicalized" after all?

Comment: See [Is int type in Dart a value type or reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62675194/) Note that lrn is a member of the Dart language team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any programming language, data can be passed either by reference or by value.

If you pass by reference, it only creates a new identifier which points to the same variable. So if you make any change to either of the variable it will reflected in both variable because they are basically 2 names pointing to a common memory address

If you pass by value, it creates a completely new variable with a separate memory allocation, thus there is no link between these two variables, thus changing in one variable won't reflect in another variable.

As stated in your question, the types int, double, String, and bool are passed as values, so the value wont update in second variable, but other data types will be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I think the information you provided is correct, but unfortunately I can't confirm that information in the official Dart / Flutter documentation.

Is Dart included in "any programming language"?

Is the definition listed in the official Dart / Flutter documentation?

Or if I can see where the definition is in documentation in other languages, I'd love to see it.

It would be very helpful if you could show me the source.

Comment: It is a general programing concept and thus dart is also included in this. The dart documentations says:

In Dart, all types are reference types, meaning that all variables refer to an object (an instance of a class). However, the types int, double, String, and bool are implemented to be immutable (unchanging) and are canonicalized, which means they behave as if they are value types. Here is a reference by Microsoft for C# for its data types explaining what reference type means. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.javatpoint.com/reference-data-types-in-java

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the material.

Comment: `int`s, `double`, `String`, and `bool` are still reference types.  As [lrn explained, Dart does not have value types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682833/).  However, since they are immutable, there is no observable difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am searching concrete definition of the above terms.
Or concrete sample code that clearly represents the difference of two types.

Comment: @森口万太郎 Why is this important to you?  All you need to know is that *everything* in Dart is a reference to an object.  Objects are never copied.  When you call a function, its arguments are copies of references to the original objects.

Comment: Apart from this problem, there is no more explicit and clear way to explain programming theory than using program code.

The specific definitions of "reference", "copy" and "reference type", "value type" in have not been obtained in the past exchanges.

Is it so strange to care about official or near-organizational definitions?
Without it, different people may use terms differently, making the explanation extremely abstract.

So I think it would be useful for many beginners to be shown by a concrete code sample.